Forest cover around GPS coordinates
I am trying to use the technique described in this thread:
Calculating forest cover in given area/radius using Google Earth Engine
Following is the code used to calculate forest cover around given GPS co-ordinates, within circles of 500m, 1km and 3km radius:
// Import Global Forest Change dataset.
var hansen_2020 = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8");

// Subset Global Forest Change the dataset.
var treeLoss = hansen_2020.select('loss');
var treeGain = hansen_2020.select('gain');
var treeCover = hansen_2020.select('treecover2000');
var treeCoverUpdated = treeCover.mask(treeLoss);
var greater10 = treeCoverUpdated.gte(10);
var treeCover_greater10 = treeCover.updateMask(greater10);

// Load GPS coordinates
var GPS = ee.FeatureCollection('users/MSc_project/GPSCords_allv2');

// Set 500m, 1km and 3km buffers
var GPS_500m = GPS.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.buffer(500, 1)
})
Map.addLayer(GPS_500m);

var GPS_1000m = GPS.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.buffer(1000, 1)
})
Map.addLayer(GPS_1000m);

var GPS_3000m = GPS.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.buffer(3000, 1)
})
Map.addLayer(GPS_3000m);

// Calculate forest cover
var forestImage = treeCover_greater10.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

// Count the forest cover pixels in 500m.
var forest = forestImage.reduceRegions({
  collection: GPS_500m,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  scale: 1
});

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: forest,
  description: '500m_forest_cover'});

What do the output values signify?
For a circle of 3km radius, for instance, I am getting values of 3-10 million. Surely that can't be the number of forested pixels, as there are only around 30,000 pixels of 30mX30m in a circle of that size.
Does the value indicate the total area of forested pixels?

Can you add the code for the output?

A circle of 3km radius contains about 28 million square meters so perhaps these are a measure of forest cover in square metres.
